# Keeping transposed or original matrix in the same variable without memory usage

Tags: c++, eigen

I'd like to write the following function:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd func(const Eigen::MatrixXd &matrix1, bool condition1,
                     const Eigen::MatrixXd &matrix2, bool condition2,
                     const Eigen::MatrixXd &matrix3, bool condition3) {
    const Eigen::MatrixXd &m1 = (condition1) ? matrix1 : matrix1.transpose();
    const Eigen::MatrixXd &m2 = (condition2) ? matrix2 : matrix2.transpose();
    const Eigen::MatrixXd &m3 = (condition3) ? matrix3 : matrix3.transpose();
    return m1 + m2 + m3;
}
```

Unfortunately, it exhibits slow performance at times, 10000x10000 matrices example:

```
0 transpose M1+M2+M3:    2.641621 seconds
1 transpose M1+M2+M3T:   4.142240 seconds
1 transpose M1+M2T+M3:   4.335527 seconds
2 transpose M1+M2T+M3T:  5.276609 seconds
1 transpose M1T+M2+M3:   3.844055 seconds
2 transpose M1T+M2+M3T:  6.080098 seconds
2 transpose M1T+M2T+M3:  5.448039 seconds
3 transpose M1T+M2T+M3T: 6.644677 seconds
```

The issue lies in the line `const Eigen::MatrixXd &m = (condition) ? matrix : matrix.transpose();`, which creates a new transposed matrix, resulting in additional computational overhead and memory usage.

Using `Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::MatrixXd> m = matrix.transpose()` would avoid unnecessary memory allocation, but it cannot be employed to store both the transposed and original matrices.

My question is: How can I optimize the function above to avoid matrix copying without resorting to a multitude of if-else statements?

Thank you.

Edit: I've asked the same question on Eigen developers Discord, they answered, that using if-else branches is the the best approach in this case.

Comment: Do you know `conditionX` at compile-time (could you pass them via template parameters)? Or could you call `func` like `func(m1.transpose(), m2, m3.transpose())` (if that is possible, you could rewrite `func` to avoid temporaries for the transpositions -- it would not help, if you would call `func(cond1 ? m1.transpose() : m1, ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you are enforcing conversion to `const Eigen::MatrixXd &`. Transpose returns `Eigen::Transpose< MatrixType >` proxy object. Avoiding doing conversion should prevent creating explicit copy.

Now merging ternary operator into expression with addition probably will not help, since ternary operator must select common type. This will enforce conversion.

So to avoid implicit conversion I would try use this kind of code:

```cpp
void addMaybeTransposed(Eigen::MatrixXd &dest, const Eigen::MatrixXd &src, bool transpose)
{
    if (transpose) {
        dest += src.transpose();
    } else {
        dest += src;
    }
}

Eigen::MatrixXd func(const Eigen::MatrixXd &matrix1, bool condition1,
                     const Eigen::MatrixXd &matrix2, bool condition2,
                     const Eigen::MatrixXd &matrix3, bool condition3) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd result{ matrix1.rows(), matrix1.cols() };
    addMaybeTransposed(result, matrix1, condition1);
    addMaybeTransposed(result, matrix2, condition2);
    addMaybeTransposed(result, matrix3, condition3);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is unfortunately sub-optimal, since you access `dest` multiple times, and in the worst case you transpose 3 matrices (instead of adding them first and transposing once). But I don't see an obvious solution without a big `if`-`else`-tree (if there are only 3 conditions, it is "just" 8 branches, but maybe OP wants a more generic solution as well ...)

Comment: I'm not expert in Eigen so you probably right. I'm just pointing out what is a root cause of observed problem.

Comment: @chtz I can manually write all 8 branches, but I just wanted to avoid it since such a construction looks slightly ugly. And I hoped there is an Eigen type that deals with both types of matrices.
Also, your example of non-optimality is not so important for me: in a real case, I use multiplication, not addition (I used addition here just to make the transpose effect more noticable in my example).

Anyway, I'll wait for some time hoping for a more elegant solution than 8 if-else branches.

Comment: How would you add `result` of `matrix1.rows() * matrix1.cols()` to `matrix1`, if `matrix1` is supposed to be transposed due to `condition1` = true?

Comment: Re "I use multiplication, not addition": Can you post code which is actually closer to what you really want to do? When doing multiplication additional transposition usually does not hurt too much, comparatively)

Comment: Most probably his matrices are square otherwise original code do not make seance. Unless `conditionX` depends on `matrixX` dimensions.

Comment: @chtz Code snippet: https://codverter.com/src/maineditor?query=01d879ba-43b6-44d0-997b-e5394a6eeb9d 

Sorry for a third-part website (it's just a text editor), I'd prefer not to create a new message here.

Comment: @11 You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77805735/edit) your original question (though it is actually bad if the edit invalidates existing answers). And the linked document does not show how you actually use this.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish it via recursion of template functions. Generic lambdas have made this a bit easier.

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXd func(
    const Eigen::MatrixXd &matrix1, bool condition1,
    const Eigen::MatrixXd &matrix2, bool condition2,
    const Eigen::MatrixXd &matrix3, bool condition3)
{
    auto add3 = [&](const auto& left) -> Eigen::MatrixXd {
        return condition3 ?
            (left + matrix3.transpose()).eval() :
            (left + matrix3).eval();
    };
    auto add2 = [&](const auto& left) -> Eigen::MatrixXd {
        return condition2 ?
            add3(left + matrix2.transpose()) :
            add3(left + matrix2);
    };
    return condition1 ? add2(matrix1.transpose()) : add2(matrix1);
}
```

Note that this will lead to significant code bloat since every possible combination will be instantiated but it will result in properly optimized code paths.

In theory [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) should be able to handle this but I wasn't able to get a reasonable solution to compile.